# stageWebView is not working on my samsung nexus device

Tags: android, flash, air

I have following code And it is working fine in AIR device simulator on my desktop. But when i install it on device(samsung nexus with Android 2.3)  it is loading nothing.

```
code:


import flash.media.StageWebView;
import flash.events.LocationChangeEvent;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;


var wv:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
    wv.viewPort = new Rectangle(0,0.stage.width,stage.height);
    wv.stage = stage;
    wv.loadURL("http://unitedmindset.com/jonbcampos");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the stage.stageWidth and stage.stageHeight propreties of the stage.

wv.viewPort = new Rectangle(0,0.stage.stageWidth ,stage.stageHeight);

the stage.width returns 0 and that is why you can't see the StageWebView.